# Column formatting for multi-choice field in SP Modern

Tags: choice-field, formatting, multiple-values, json-formatting

*Context: I'm working as a regular user consuming my company's modern Sharepoint deployment, so my capabilities are pretty limited other than what's available from the GUI.*

I'm trying to format a multi-selection Choice field so that it looks like tags, like the image below:
[image: image of text and text inside of tag containers]

When SP outputs the field, it looks like this: "Apple,Cherry,Plum". I an add formatting before and after the text, but I can't separate the individual members.

I've also tried to use a Calculated field to pull in the multi-selection Choice field and output a string I could then manipulate a little easier with field formulas, but apparently Calculated fields don't work with multi-selection Choice fields(?).

Any suggestions appreciated!